# Excel Large function with multiple ranges AND conditions/criterias/If-Statements

Tags: excel

Im having a problem with the Large Function in Excel. Im trying to get the second largest value from a column which contains numbers and strings. Each string in the column tells which type the number above is. I want to get the second largest value of the numbers from a specific type. The picture here illustrates the situation:

[image]

Each second Row holds information about the Row above it. Here im trying to get the second largest value of the numbers which have the string "SW" underneath it. The Number-type cannot be placed in another column. Both informations need to be in the same column for this application.

I figured I needed to include the IF-function into the Large-function for multiple cells. But it does not work.

Here is the setup:

- Cell A1 contains the value 10, A2 contains "RW", A3=5, A4="SW", A5=3, A6="SW".
- A7 is the cell with the Large-function and should only take the compare the cells A3 and A5, because there both of type "SW".

I tried the following in A7

```
=large((If(A2="SW",A1,0),If(A4="SW",A3,0),If(A6="SW",A5,0)),2)
```

If all the strings are = "SW", then the formula works, but as soon as one row is "RW", an error is returned saying: "#VALUE!. How can I solve this without any helper-columns or helper-rows?

Answer (score 0):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,A1:A5/(A2:A6="SW"),2)
```

Note the same size but offset ranges:

[image]